# Google chrome issue with security when loading the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Could you please help me with the following problem:

The website I created used to work fine until recently I noticed I can't open some of the pages. Using Google Chrome I noticed the security warning "this page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources". The website is [http:www.ekspert-m.com](http://http:www.ekspert-m.com)

The errors shown are the following:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ekspert-m.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, 
>       but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'. 
>       This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>       bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function
>
> ```
>     at bootstrap.min.js:6
>     at bootstrap.min.js:6
> ```

Comment: Have you followed the error to use HTTPS: **the content must be served over HTTPS** by using `https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js`?

Comment: thanks, solved now.